# Reference direction for current and voltage?

Tags: electric-circuits, conventions

So I just began a course on introductory circuits but I am really confused when I see voltages labelled as negative or when I see current as negative. I'm not really sure how I'm meant to interpret this or use it in calculations. My professor simply stated that for the current it means the reference direction chosen, it's going in the other direction. But don't we always assume current flows from positive to negative? How can we choose a direction for it ??

Comment: Dou you know Kirchhoff's circuit laws? It states that the algebraic sum of currents in a network of conductors is zero at a node which known as Kirchhoff's current law, and the directed sum of the electrical potential differences (voltage) around any closed network is zero which known as Kirchhoff's voltage law. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws

Comment: -1. Unclear. Why does assuming a direction for current pose a difficulty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a complicated circuit, you often don't know ahead of time, before doing calculations, which direction the current will flow in.  So you choose a direction and do the calculations assuming that direction, and then if you get a negative answer you know that the current is actually flowing in the opposite direction of the one you chose.

Comment: But do you do the calculations assuming its negative or positive for the current. Thanks

Comment: You do the calculations with the current as a variable, which can be either positive or negative, and then if that variable turns out to be negative then the current is actually flowing in the opposite direction from the one you chose.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a relatively simple circuit.

[image]

You can be certain that in terms of potentials $V_{\rm A} > V_{\rm B} > V_{\rm C}$ and $V_{\rm A} > V_{\rm D} > V_{\rm C}$ and so chosen current directions $i_1, i_2, i_3$ and $i_4$ do give the current directions as current flows from a region of high potential to a region of low potential.

What you do not know is which of potentials $V_{\rm B}$ and $V_{\rm D}$ is the higher.
This also means that you do not know the direction of current $i_5$.

So you make a choice as to the current direction and do the sums.

If you found that $i_5 = + 2\, \rm A$ then the current is flowing in the direction of the arrow and $ V_{\rm B}>V_{\rm D}$

If you found that $i_5 = - 2\, \rm A$ then the current is flowing in the opposite direction to that of the arrow, ie from node $D$ to node $B$,  and $ V_{\rm B}<V_{\rm D}$.

Comment: There is no incorrect guess for the reference direction of current (or the reference polarity for voltage).  If I connect an ammeter and read -2A, I have not connected the ammeter incorrectly but this is no different from choosing a reference direction.  In the final analysis, the -2A reading gives precisely the same information as an ammeter connected oppositely that reads +2A.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I understand what you are saying and it is equivalent to adding a adding a centre zero analogue or digital ammeter to the circuit without think about the current direction. The ammeter will have a red  $(+)$ labelled terminal and a black $(-)$ labelled terminal on it.  If you get a reading of $- 2\, \rm A$ on the ammeter then you know that the  current is going into the ammeter through the black $(-)$ labelled terminal and coming out of the red $(-)$ labelled terminal. So now you have found the direction of the current.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I have changed to word "guess" to "choice" and so removed any connotation regarding trying to predict the result.